# Firebase Functions not sending Notification

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I have been using Functions for about 2 weeks on one of my news applications. However I have created a second news application with different news. The invocation of the PN happens using a web hook that is sending the data about the article to all the subscribed people for the topic. If I use the web hook to my previous app, it is working perfectly. I have used the same Functions code from the old app and have pasted it to the new app, and it is not working.

I have:

- Checked if I receive notifications on my iPhone for certain topic when I send them using FCM/APNS - Working
- Checked the code and the format of the notifications - It is OK
- Made tests if other functions are invoked - Working
- Phone is subscribed for pushes - It is
- Device subscribed for topic - It is. Tested with FCM topic push.
- Method swizzling enabled - It is

Here is the code for the functions:

```javascript
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();


exports.sentNotify = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
 console.log("notification request received");
 console.log(request.body);
 let topic = "Martin";//request.body.primaryCategory;
 let hottness = request.body.hottness;
 let title = request.body.title;
 let description = request.body.description;
 let thumbnail = request.body.thumbnail;
 let link = request.body.url;

 const messagePayload = {
   notification: {
     title: title,
     body: description,
     icon: 'thumbnail',
     sound: 'default',
     badge: '0'
   },
   data:{
     link_url: link,
     category: "NEWS_CATEGORY"
   }
 };

 const options = {
        priority: "high",
        timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24
    };

 return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic, messagePayload, options)
.then(() => {
    response.send("OK")
    return;
    });
});
```

And here is the request that I am sending:

```cmd
curl -X "POST" "https://us-central1-<my-app>.cloudfunctions.net/sentNotify" \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' \
     -d $'{
  "hotness": 7000,
  "thumbail": "thumbnail",
  "title": "Title",
  "publishedAt": "2018-08-24T12:37:08.000Z",
  "description": "This is the description",
  "primaryCategory": "General",
  "url": "https://google.com"
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You're sending a response before to the client before sending the message:

```
response.send("OK")
```

When you send a response from an HTTPS type function, that effectively terminates the function.  Any subsequent code **may not execute** (it is not deterministic), as Cloud Functions reserves the right to clamp down any further resources after the response is sent.  This means that your message may not be sent at all.

Only send a response from an HTTPS function **after** you are done with all work, including asynchronous work (such as sending a message).  This means you should arrange for a response to be sent only after the message is finally delivered:

```
return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic, messagePayload, options)
.then(() => {
    response.send("OK")
})
```

See the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) for more details.